# Can't access iframe of different origin in the parent jsp

Tags: apache, jsp, iframe, ssl

Quick example for the kind of functionality required (just for exampple):

http://www.indeed.hk/cmp/Calvin-Klein-Jeans-&-Calvin-Klein-Underwear/jobs/Part-Time-Sales-Associate-1643e24903d9f4c7

If you click on apply-now button, it shows an iframe.

I am having a project where I am trying to access an iframe of different origin, say `https: //subdomain.example.com`, on a jsp page of origin say `http://www.example.com` but it gives me the following error:

> Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin http://www.example.com from accessing a frame with origin https://subdomain.example.com. The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Lets call the parent jsp page as parent.jsp, and the iframe jsp as iframe.jsp.
parent.jsp is on server S, and the project name is xyznet
iframe.jsp is on server R, and the project name is xyz

Here is a piece of code from the **parent.jsp**

```
<%
    java.util.Map model = (java.util.Map)pageContext.findAttribute("model");
%>
<html>
 <body>
 <h1> This is the parent page
    <iframe id="quick-apply-frame" name="iframe-name" src="       <%=https: //sub.domain.com/apply.html?ref=${model.x.y}" onload="quickSetParams();">
    </iframe>
<script>
 function quickSetParams() {
 $("[name=iframe-name]").contents().find("[name=iframe-param-name]").val(${model.value1}');
}
</body>
</html>
```

And here is piece of code from the **iframe.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="xyz.html">
    <input name="iframe-parm-name" value=""/>
     <input name="iframe-parm-name2" value="${model.parm2}" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Handler which loads the iframe.jsp is a SimpleFormController, located on server R

I have come across some solutions where the data is transferred directly using javascript, but I need a handler for this, and so, a direct javascript redirect or nesting of iframes would not work for me

Comment: Can't you just force the parent to use https by doing a redirect if necessary? Is the SSL certificate not valid for the base domain?

Comment: Also, the example you linked to is not using an iframe, it is using a div. If you wanted to do something similar, have a look at JQuery and in particular, the JQuery UI dialog (see http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-form.html for an example)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James for some leads. I finally got it working!

I still dont completely understand how it works, but here is what I did:

I dont load the iframe.jsp (located in https: //sub.domain.com) at the same time as the parent.jsp is loaded. Means, the src of the iframe is not set initially.
 Instead, I call a javascript function to load the iframe once the "showIframe" button in the parent is clicked. I got a suggestion from someone that to crack cross domain security issue, you have to set the src of the iframe via javascript after the page loads.

Some more pointers other can explore is CORS, where you add a parameter like this in your ssl.conf or httpd.conf (apache configuration)
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.domain.com" . It basically grants permission to access to the domain mentioned